# How do i remove the needed usage of quotes for my suggest command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I made a suggest command but if the user dont add quotes to their sentence it will only pick the first word they typed **example**: *-suggest this is a test.*
It will only pick the 'This' any fixes for this?

The command code lines:

```
@client.command()
async def suggest(ctx, suggestion):
    channel = client.get_channel(754640430670413835)
    embed = discord.Embed(color=0xff0000)
    embed.add_field(name="SUGGESTION", value="{} suggested this: ** {} **".format(ctx.author.mention, suggestion), inline=False)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
    await ctx.send("Thank you for your suggestion {}".format(ctx.author.mention))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask the library to give you the rest as a single argument. We do this by using a keyword-only argument. Add a `*` before your `suggestion` parameter.

```py
@client.command()
async def suggest(ctx, *, suggestion):
    channel = client.get_channel(754640430670413835)
    embed = discord.Embed(color=0xff0000)
    embed.add_field(name="SUGGESTION", value="{} suggested this: ** {} **".format(ctx.author.mention, suggestion), inline=False)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
    await ctx.send("Thank you for your suggestion {}".format(ctx.author.mention))
```